# How to get data from file which has no extension in Android?

Tags: java, android, parsing, character-encoding

I have a file and I want to parse data from this file. I tried but I can't get data which I want. I tried to copy/paste of my .data file but it didn't work because of some character that are included in my file.

Link of my file http://bit.ly/11meGwG

I don't know which type of file is this?

How to decode this?

```
InputStream is = null;
is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);
InputStreamReader isr = null;
isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String line;
try {
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(line);
        sb.append(line+"\n");

    }
    isr.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `openRawResource()`. This has nothing to do with your `assets/` folder. `openRawResource()` is for your `res/raw/` folder.

Use `getAssets().open()` to open a file within `assets/`.

Comment: ya it's true but it is not my problem actually i don't understand how to parse the file.i didn't get the actual data from this file.which type of formatting(encoding) used in this file do you know that?

Comment: @user2186857: "which type of formatting(encoding) used in this file" -- how am I supposed to know? **It is your file**. Out of ~8 billion people on the planet, you are the only one who can possibly know what the format and encoding is of your own file.